# Html/css: Create responsive image gallery grid with figcaption that fits width of content

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, css-grid

**Goal**: I am trying to create an image gallery grid using flexbox for my website that

1. can contain any number of photos,
2. contains a text figcaption at the bottom describing the images, and
3. is responsive for mobile.

**Problem**: I am struggling to get the width to work properly on the grid container. It seems to stretch to 100% of the parent div width and I cannot get it to shrink to fit the content of *both the images and text figcaption.*

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

#container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

.gridcontainer {
    margin: 0 auto;

    border: 2px solid #54d9ff;
    border-style: outset;
    }

.gridbox {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    }

.gridbox img {
    height: max-content;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 15px;

    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .gridbox img {
        width: 90%;
        }
    }

.gridtext {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;

    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;

    background-image: linear-gradient(#c4c4c4, #787878);
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="gridcontainer">
                <div class="gridbox">
                        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/820/200/300.jpg?hmac=oyShjC6apmZncG0xgz0zZEnh_1_j8eCRZnF8QxQ_PsE"/>
                        <!--<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/641/300/400.jpg?hmac=1xemcP7Oep2uO8c3Ekp3XcwY1S57YinXY4DTBd_GBbg"/>
                        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/296/150/150.jpg?hmac=SSKcpx6mZuURJcKscRI27o7N2eS9iOh90116Rbdv1oc"/>
                        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/541/600/270.jpg?hmac=qunG5B_lvK78sqhpBtHAPCRlMr6ciT2ZvMbxd6-8Mis"/>
                        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/363/500/300.jpg?hmac=LZnmPmpU0TqF3LE_p3fn--rmS-Qwlc3pXmBS-Aax_2k"/>-->
                </div>
                <div class="gridtext">
                    Images from Lorem Picsum
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

This 3 column grid displays 100% width of Parent Div. This is ok given there are multiple images.

[image]

This is a 1 column grid but the container div is still stretching to 100% of the parent div. This is NOT ok since I want the container to shrink to the content of the image and figcaption.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to show the relevant bit of your current html/css for tips on how to do that; but i would say that it sounds like you'd be better served by a `grid` than `flex`box layout (they're extremely similar; `grid` is effectively an extension of `flex`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+gris+figcaption+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @Raxi I just added the HTML and CSS. I'll look into grid to see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this template using Bootstrap

```
<html>
<head>
  <!--Basic Page Needs-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image Gallery</title>
  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
  <!--bootstrap.min css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
<section class="products section bg-gray">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="title text-center">
                <h2>Products</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div>                       
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/images/shop/products/product-1.jpg" alt="product-img">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4><a href="product-single.html">Reef Boardsport</a></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/images/shop/products/product-2.jpg" alt="product-img">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4><a href="product-single.html">Rainbow Shoes</a></h4>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/images/shop/products/product-3.jpg" alt="product-img">
                    
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4><a href="product-single.html">Strayhorn SP</a></h4>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/images/shop/products/product-4.jpg" alt="product-img">
                    
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4><a href="product-single.html">Bradley Mid</a></h4>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/images/shop/products/product-5.jpg" alt="product-img">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4><a href="product-single.html">Rainbow Shoes</a></h4>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/images/shop/products/product-6.jpg" alt="product-img">
                    
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4><a href="product-single.html">Rainbow Shoes</a></h4>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="bage">Sale</span>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/images/shop/products/product-7.jpg" alt="product-img">
                    
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4><a href="product-single.html">Rainbow Shoes</a></h4>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/images/shop/products/product-8.jpg" alt="product-img">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4><a href="product-single.html">Rainbow Shoes</a></h4>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://demo.themefisher.com/aviato/images/shop/products/product-9.jpg" alt="product-img">
                    
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4><a href="product-single.html">Rainbow Shoes</a></h4>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```